# SQL using DateRange and DATETIME Column to find status at noon every day with in range

Tags: sql, datetime, common-table-expression

Using the following data:

```
    Item    Record  StatType      statStart                 statEnd
    Plow    8860    Operational   2017-08-29 16:59:48.907   2017-11-06 15:35:15.290
    Plow    8859    Inspection    2017-08-29 16:56:59.460   2017-08-29 16:58:48.907
    Plow    8830    Operational   2017-08-23 18:38:45.530   2017-08-29 16:55:59.460
    Plow    8730    Inspection    2017-07-31 15:34:10.387   2017-08-23 18:37:45.530
    Plow    8625    Operational   2017-07-17 11:22:00.000   2017-07-31 15:33:10.387
    Plow    8615    Inspection    2017-07-17 09:22:58.127   2017-07-17 11:21:00.000
    Plow    8406    Operational   2017-06-05 14:42:32.837   2017-07-17 09:21:58.127
    Plow    8399    Inspection    2017-06-02 17:02:55.107   2017-06-05 14:41:32.837
    Plow    8332    Operational   2017-05-23 09:30:37.707   2017-06-02 17:01:55.107
```

I need to find the StatType of the Plow at Noon everyday between @startDate and @endDate.  You will notice that record #8615 has a statStart of 9:22 am and statEnd of 11:21 am.  This record should not return as part of the result set.  Also, since the statType will not change between records 8406 & 8625 due to 8615 being omitted, I will need to carry the status forward to count the DATEDIFF (or StatusDays) accurately.

I have tried MANY different approaches including combinations of LAG / LEAD and CTE's, however, because the one record 8615 does not meet the Noon criteria, it creates a "GAP' in time that is negatively affecting my SSRS chart.  Notice that 8406 ends at 9:21 but 8625 does not begin until 11:22.

I am hoping that someone might be able to help me create the part of my query that will allow me to get the status for everyday at noon between two date parameters.

Thank you!

Update: Using Sam cd's solution, I get the following results (below).  Notice that when joining to the dates CTE suggested, the result set omits record 8615, and the statEnd of record 8406 is 1.5 hours less than the statStart of record 8625.  That 1.5 hour gap is where record 8615 would normally be.  This gap is causing an issue in my bar chart on SSRS because I need the status of Operational to flow through the gap and also the StatusDays to read '56' (42 + 14) all the way until record 8730.

Updated Result set:

```
   Item Record  statusDate              statType    statStart               statEnd                 StatusDays
   Plow 8406    2017-07-15 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-06-05 14:42:32.837 2017-07-17 09:21:58.127 42
   Plow 8406    2017-07-16 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-06-05 14:42:32.837 2017-07-17 09:21:58.127 42
   Plow 8625    2017-07-17 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
   Plow 8625    2017-07-18 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
   Plow 8625    2017-07-19 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
   Plow 8625    2017-07-20 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
   Plow 8625    2017-07-21 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
   Plow 8625    2017-07-22 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
   Plow 8625    2017-07-23 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
   Plow 8625    2017-07-24 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
   Plow 8625    2017-07-25 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
   Plow 8625    2017-07-26 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
   Plow 8625    2017-07-27 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
   Plow 8625    2017-07-28 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
   Plow 8625    2017-07-29 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
   Plow 8625    2017-07-30 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
   Plow 8625    2017-07-31 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
   Plow 8730    2017-08-01 12:00:00.000 Inspection  2017-07-31 15:34:10.387 2017-08-23 18:37:45.530 23
   Plow 8730    2017-08-02 12:00:00.000 Inspection  2017-07-31 15:34:10.387 2017-08-23 18:37:45.530 23
```

**UPDATE 2**: My query (I don't know if this will help..)

```
DECLARE @StartDate datetime = '07/15/2017'
DECLARE @EndDate datetime = '07/31/2017'
DECLARE @item varchar (10) = 'Plow'

;WITH CTE_Data AS
    (
    SELECT        
 item 
,record 
,statType 
,statStart 

,CASE WHEN DATEADD(minute, - 1, LEAD(t1.statStart) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.item ORDER BY t1.statStart)) IS NULL THEN GETDATE()
ELSE DATEADD(minute, - 1, LEAD(t1.statStart) OVER (PARTITION BY t1.item ORDER BY t1.statStart)) END  as statEnd

FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.record = t2.record

AND t1.active = 'Y'
AND t1.item = @item
),

cte_Dates AS 
(
select dateadd(hour,12,@startDate)  AS StatusDate
union ALL
select dateadd(day,1,StatusDate)
from cte_Dates
where StatusDate < dateadd(day,1,@endDate)
) ,

CTE_Sample as
(
SELECT 
cted.statusdate
,Item
,Record
,StatType 
,statStart
,statEnd

,CASE
WHEN DATEDIFF(day, statStart, statEnd) IS NULL 
    THEN DATEDIFF(day, statStart, GETDATE()) 
WHEN DATEDIFF(day, statStart, statEnd) = 0
    THEN 1 ELSE DATEDIFF(day, statStart, statEnd)
END as StatusDays

FROM CTE_Data
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_Dates cted ON cted.statusDate >= statStart AND    cted.statusDate <= statEnd
WHERE cted.statusdate between @StartDate and @EndDate 
)

SELECT Item, Record, statusDate, statType,  statStart, statEnd,  StatusDays     FROM CTE_Sample 
WHERE statusdate between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

As you can see, I am "creating" the statEnd using the LEAD function and when I join it to CTE_Dates, the StatusDate column is added and a record is created for each day of the date range - but the gap still exist between 8406 & 8625.

```
    Item    Record  statusDate              statType    statStart               statEnd                 StatusDays
    Plow    8406    2017-07-15 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-06-05 14:42:32.837 2017-07-17 09:21:58.127 42
    Plow    8406    2017-07-16 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-06-05 14:42:32.837 2017-07-17 09:21:58.127 42
    Plow    8625    2017-07-17 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
    Plow    8625    2017-07-18 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
    Plow    8625    2017-07-19 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
    Plow    8625    2017-07-20 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
    Plow    8625    2017-07-21 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
    Plow    8625    2017-07-22 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
    Plow    8625    2017-07-23 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
    Plow    8625    2017-07-24 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
    Plow    8625    2017-07-25 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
    Plow    8625    2017-07-26 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
    Plow    8625    2017-07-27 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
    Plow    8625    2017-07-28 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
    Plow    8625    2017-07-29 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
    Plow    8625    2017-07-30 12:00:00.000 Operational 2017-07-17 11:22:00.000 2017-07-31 15:33:10.387 14
```

Comment: What about record 8859?  That does not occur during noon either. Should it be omitted?

Comment: Zorkolot - It is omitted in the updated result set, my apologies for not picturing in the update above.  I was trying to save space.  All records that do not "cross" the noon deadline are omitted and create a time gap.  The omission is necessary, but I need to circumvent the time gap. Basically, whatever the status of an item is at noon on that day is the status for that day regardless of status changed that don't encompass the noon time stamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a dates table using recursive CTE:

declare @startDate datetime = '2017-11-01'
,@enddate datetime = '2017-11-30'

```
;with dts as (
select dateadd(hour,12,@startDate) noon
union ALL
select dateadd(day,1,noon)
from dts
where noon < dateadd(day,1,@endDate)
)
```

then join to your table to get the status

```
select
d.noon
,st.StatType
from statusTable st
 inner join dts d
  on d.noon between st.statStart and st.statEnd
```

Comment: thank you!  I have a cte for dates and joined it to another cte using the same method you suggested.  My date CTE is identical to yours as luck would have it.  I posted the result set above and hope it helps to identify the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're trying to do something like below.  I use a CTE... in it I add an index number (the ROW_NUMBER) and ordered the rows by statStart.  I exclude non-noon values in the WHERE clause.  To eliminate the 'gap', you can select the startstat of the next ROW_NUMBER.  I do not use the original endtime value.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (Item varchar(100), Record int, StatType varchar(100), statStart datetime, statEnd datetime)
INSERT INTO @temp VALUES
 ('Plow', 8860, 'Operational', '2017-08-29 16:59:48.907', '2017-11-06 15:35:15.290')
,('Plow', 8859, 'Inspection', '2017-08-29 16:56:59.460', '2017-08-29 16:58:48.907')
,('Plow', 8830, 'Operational', '2017-08-23 18:38:45.530', '2017-08-29 16:55:59.460')
,('Plow', 8730, 'Inspection', '2017-07-31 15:34:10.387', '2017-08-23 18:37:45.530')
,('Plow', 8625, 'Operational', '2017-07-17 11:22:00.000', '2017-07-31 15:33:10.387')
,('Plow', 8615, 'Inspection', '2017-07-17 09:22:58.127', '2017-07-17 11:21:00.000')
,('Plow', 8406, 'Operational', '2017-06-05 14:42:32.837', '2017-07-17 09:21:58.127')
,('Plow', 8399, 'Inspection', '2017-06-02 17:02:55.107', '2017-06-05 14:41:32.837')
,('Plow', 8332, 'Operational', '2017-05-23 09:30:37.707', '2017-06-02 17:01:55.107')

DECLARE @startDate datetime = '2017-07-15 12:00:00'
       ,@endDate datetime   = '2017-08-03 12:00:00';

WITH cte AS
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY statStart) [idval]
       ,T.*
  FROM @temp T --your tablename
 WHERE (CAST(statStart as time) < '12:00:00' AND CAST(statEnd as time) > '12:00:00'
        OR
        DATEDIFF(HOUR, statStart, statEnd) >= 24
       )
)
,
cte2 AS
(
SELECT @startDate as dateval
UNION ALL 
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, 1, dateval)
  FROM cte2
 WHERE dateval < @endDate
)

SELECT C2.dateval, dT.Item, dT.Record, dT.StatType, dT.statStart, dT.StatEnd
      ,DATEDIFF(DAY, statStart, StatEnd) [StatusDays]
  FROM (
        SELECT C.idval, C.Item, C.Record, C.StatType, C.statStart --, C.statEnd --this has the 'gap'
              ,COALESCE((SELECT MAX(C2.statStart) FROM cte C2 WHERE C2.idval > C.idval AND C2.StatType = C.StatType), C.statEnd) AS [StatEnd]
          FROM cte C
       ) AS dT
               INNER JOIN cte2 C2 ON C2.dateval between dT.statStart AND dT.[StatEnd]
```

Comment: @Zorkolot- This is good! but, remember, I have to find the status of every day between a date range.  End user inputs the parameters StartDate and EndDate of their range.  For example: what is the status for the plow on 5-24-2017, 5-25-2017, 5-26-2017, so on.. Status will show on each individual date.  With your result set, I am not sure how to get the status for a specific day.. I truly appreciate your help and I think if I can overcome that one thing I can move on with this report.  Getting the data to that point I've accomplished - getting the results I need? Not so much.

Comment: @JustPeachy I've edited the answer; by adding a 2nd cte for the dates and changed the algorithm to check for the same StatType.  Hopefully that answers your request?

Comment: My attention was redirected for a bit - my apologies.  These seems to have worked!